# next.js 14 unable to dislpay loading.tsx

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js14

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVGtb.png)

loading not display  when navigate to  /profile
†
how to show the loading ?

```
export default function Loading() {
  // You can add any UI inside Loading, including a Skeleton.
  return (
    <div>
      loading..oading..oading..oading..oading..oading..oading..oading..oading..oading..oading..oading..oading..oading..oading..oading...
    </div>
  );
}

type Props = Readonly<{ children: React.ReactNode }>;

export default function Layout({ children }: Props) {
  return <div>this is profile layout {children}</div>;
}

import Link from 'next/link';

export default function About() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>profile page</div>
      <Link href="/">Dashboard</Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

> *loading not display when navigate to /profile † how to show the loading ?*

**Solution :**

> Add `loading.js/.tsx` file in app directory at root `app/loading.js or loading.tsx`.

**Please Read :**

1. **loading.js :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/loading